# google tag manager how to set environment name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-tag-manager

I am using google tag manager and google analytics with the plugin called [vue-gtm](https://github.com/mib200/vue-gtm)

I created 3 environments in google tag manager under the same container.

As a user defined variable, I created `look up table` called GA from environment and i set input variable there `{{ Environment Name}}`. Output variables are like:

1. dev - ua_123_1
2. staging - ua_456_1
3. prod - ua_789_1

Here is how vue-gtm looks like:

```js
Vue.use(VueGtm, {
  id: config.services.googleTag.id,
  queryParams: config.services.googleTag.gtm_auth ? { // Add url query string when load gtm.js with GTM ID (optional)
    gtm_auth: config.services.googleTag.gtm_auth,
    gtm_preview: config.services.googleTag.gtm_preview,
    gtm_cookies_win: config.services.googleTag.gtm_cookies_win,
  } : {},
  defer: false, // defaults to false. Script can be set to `defer` to increase page-load-time at the cost of less accurate results (in case visitor leaves before script is loaded, which is unlikely but possible)
  enabled: true, // defaults to true. Plugin can be disabled by setting this to false for Ex: enabled: !!GDPR_Cookie (optional)
  debug: true, // Whether or not display console logs debugs (optional)
  vueRouter: router, // Pass the router instance to automatically sync with router (optional)
});
```

After entering the site, in the analytics nothing happen, because in the debug, i can still see that environment name variable is set to something like: `'Preview Environment 2 2020-08-05 071543'` . No idea why .

Should I be the one who should be setting this from the code ? I don't think so, since I am using `gtm_preview` and all that so that it can automatically figure that out. any ideas ?

Comment: Echoing that this is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**if you want to debug specific env - you need to preview exactly this env (i.e. "dev")**

GTM -> Admin -> Environments -> "dev" -> Actions -> Share Link -> enter Destination URL -> copy generated preview link -> go to generated link -> now you will see "dev" in variables

[tagassistant debug variables screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz5b3.png)

*Note*: Destination URL - site where you have configured this env (added auth, preview & cookie query params). Can be localhost, as well